# Baby monitor that can have multiple transmitting stations on the same channel

Tags: audio

The baby monitors I have experience with have two channels. The channels are labeled "A" and "B" with no indication of what frequency the two are actually using.

Different models *seem* to use different frequencies for similarly named channels.

- I am making this assumption because two base stations of different models configured to transmit on "A" are not both picked up by the receiving baby monitor.
- Two monitors of the same brand seem to cause interference if both transmit on the same channel, because the receiving monitors only pick up static.

I'd like to have a single receiving monitor for multiple transmitting monitors. I don't like having to set up multiple monitors to hear if the children are crying while I'm in the basement at night or working outside during nap time.

Is there a monitor that allows me to set up multiple monitors in the children's rooms (preferably 3), configure them all to transmit on the same channel, and only requires that I have 1 monitor to receive sound? I don't need to be able to identify which child is crying (as I could when each room had it's only individual monitor/channel). I just need to be able to hear them all so that I can walk into the hallway and determine who's making noise.

Comment: It's difficult to find a set of baby monitors with one parent and three child monitors. This and the fact that everyone is obsessed with video monitors nowadays doesn't help much. Aside from that, not many manufacturers list details about specific frequencies anymore.

Comment: [Meta discussion](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/105/are-small-electronics-on-topic) about whether is is on or off topic

Answer (score 4):

We had the same problem and found a somewhat creative solution by reactivating our old android-phones. We installed "TeamSpeak" on each of them and placed them in the childrens rooms. They connect via wlan to an old pc where TeamSpeak-Server runs.

My wife and I also have TeamSpeak-clients on our cells - so wherever we are in the house - we can always hear them.

When I'm sitting at the computer I always have a TeamSpeak-Window at the 2nd monitor, so I can even see from where the noise is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

IN 2023, you can actually buy them.  As an example this one comes with two but can be extended.

[image]

> This video baby monitor can support two cameras at the same time. You can monitor two children or rooms side by side with the additional camera and won’t miss any new motions and cute behaviors of them any more.( Additional camera is sold separately.)

Disclaimer, I am not associated with it.

Comment: Can you maybe add a brand and model number of the example so the asker can maybe buy that one?